# How to update React native android app with expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I build an android app in react native and expo. Now I made some changes to the code and was thinking that is it possible to update the app OTA for the users. My app is not published to the play store.
I tried by `expo build:apk` but this build a new apk file and earlier one has no effect on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't disabled OTA updates for your app you should be able to push an update to the existing app using `expo publish` command. Just run it in the directory of your project—the project will be built, uploaded to the servers and next time the app starts it will download the update.

See https://docs.expo.io/introduction/walkthrough/#updating-the-app-over-the-air for more information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. what i understood is i have to run `expo publish` and then `expo publish --release-channel android` to provide OTA update. One more thing that now i have already built an apk for the updated code, if i delete that apk from expo and run the above mentioned commands, will it works for me?

Answer (score 1):

`expo publish` is now deprecated. Use `eas update` now.

**[Here](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/eas-update-and-eas-cli/)** is the documentation explaining more.